# Restrictions for each item in a list based on field value

Tags: 2013, list, item

SharePoint 2013
I have a list that contain IT support incidents. I'm Admin and need access to all items. I would like following: User A access the list, the user can only read/edit items where A is listed in eg. item field Customer. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

yeah. In the list permission section give user A the permission to **View only** and the users to **Edit**.

To set the permission Go to **List -> List Settings -> Permissions for this list**.

Comment: Hmm that way the user can see all items in the list. I would like to only show items where user A is mentioned/present in a field in the item. That way the user can't see items for other users.

Comment: you can do this with the views. create a field of multiple users for each item, where you can add the users who can see this item.